# Align image and text in the same line

Tags: html, css

I want to render image and text like in this pic in 2 rows and 2columns. The gap between image and text on its right should be same when the browser width is re adjusted ( I am using media queries) (Desired apperance- https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaFcm.jpg). The problem I am facing is when I scale the browser at some point the text gets mis-aligned. It appears one line below the image.
[image]
The html and css code are in the fiddle link below. Any suggestion on what is going wrong is much appreciated. I apologize to remove the actual text.

```
div class="freedom_carousel">   <!--Freedom section -->

<p class="heading"> This is heading. </p> 

<div class="container1">
<div class="col1"><img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText Text </span></div>
<div class="col2"><img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"><b>This is</b> Text Text Text TextText TextText TextText Text </span></div>
</div>  <!--End of container 1 -->

<div class="container2">
<div class="col1"><img class="icon" src="/path/to/image"  > <span class="icon-text"><b>Access </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText TextText TextText TextText Text</span></div>
<div class="col2"><img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"><b>This is</b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText TextText TextText Text</span></div>
</div> <!--End of container 2 -->



</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwqvo65f/

If you readjust the width of result window of fiddle, it reflects my explanation. I hope that explains the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="freedom_carousel">
    <!--Freedom section -->
    <p class="heading">This is heading.</p>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="col1">
            <p>
                <img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" /> <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText Text </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <p>
                <img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" /> <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText Text </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of container 1 -->
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="col1">
            <p>
                <img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" /> <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText Text </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <p>
                <img class="icon" src="/path/to/image" /> <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> Text TextText TextText TextText TextText Text </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of container 2 -->
</div>
</div>
<!--End of Freedom carousel -->
```

and your CSS like this:

```
.freedom_carousel {
    border:2px solid red;
    float: left;
}
.freedom_carousel .heading {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueMedium", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica";
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #252525;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24pt;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.freedom_carousel .container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.freedom_carousel .container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.freedom_carousel .col1 {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 13%;
    width:40%;
}
.freedom_carousel .col2 {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}
.freedom_carousel .icon {
}
.freedom_carousel .icon-text {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueMedium", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica";
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #252525;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 22pt;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
. .features {
    border:2px solid red;
    float: left;
}
.features .heading {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueMedium", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica";
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #252525;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24pt;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.col1 p, .col2 p {
    display:block;
}
.col1 img, .col1 span, .col2 img, .col2 span {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none
}
.icon {
    width:10%;
}
.icon-text {
    width:80%
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0cr1zj89/) You will probably need to adjust the 2 last lines width values to your needs, but it will work anyways

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thanks, that partially worked when I tried it on browser. Now the text aligns in the same line as image but the second lien of text doesnt align with the first line. The second line starts where the image start. I want both the line aligned with each other with a certain width between the text and image.

PS: Strangely, this happens only in browser, not in JSfiddle.

Comment: then make sure you're using EXACTLY the same code, it sounds like you're using a float instead of an inline-block. Using block elements it's impossible to have a behavior like the one you mention

Comment: I copied the same code from stack overflow with the dummy text and image as it is.

I understand what you're saying and the behavior of the code is confusing for me too.

Comment: OK, this is really strange, but try adding padding-bottom:30px to .icon and/or overflow:hidden to .icon-text, it shouldn't be necessary at all, but should do the trick.

Comment: Thank yo very much. Having over flow worked.

I want the image aligned with the first line. Right now, its aligned with the second (or last line, if there is more than 2 lines of text). Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: UPDATE: I got that working by changing float:none to float:left in img and span tag in col1 and col2.

Thank you, Fabio. I want to upvote your answer. Being new on this forum, I can not.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the icons and the text in the same p tag or something like that like this:

```
<p><img class='icone'/> text in here </p>
```